# Change font in gtk textview

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

Is it possible to change a font in gtk textview without using css in python?

I tried using `override_font` and `modify_font` but it shows depreciation warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows a deprecation warning because you're supposed to use CSS to do this. You either have to use CSS or ignore the deprecation warning.